# obtain data from a listview from a button on an activity

Tags: android, button, android-listview

I have an activity that contains a listview.
In the same activity, not inside the listview, there is a button.
When I click an item in the listview get the row data, but I want to press the button to get a specific data row.

To get data from the row, use:

```
String urlImage = (galleryWebList.get(position).get(KEY_URL_IMAGE));
```

I've tried;

```
moreInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
    public void onClick(View view){ 

        int position = 0;

        String urlImage = (galleryWebList.get(position).get(KEY_URL_IMAGE));        

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), urlImage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: ar you passing an collection or Array as DataSource to Adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are passing `HashMap<String, String>` as data source to Adapter then try it as to get item on Button Click:

```
HashMap<String, String> hashmap = (HashMap<String, String>) 
                              galleryWebList.getAdapter().getItem(position);
String urlImage = hashmap.get(KEY_URL_IMAGE));
```